# How would I display my ready player me avatar into a profile picture

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, avatar

Hello everyone I was wondering if anyone could help me with my current situation. I was wanting to know does anybody know how I could upload my players ready player me avatars into in a small window on our web page (without modification options - just the final avatar, nothing else). This will need to be in JavaScript and HTML

Comment: What do you have so far ? can you provide your code to see what the issue is

Comment: I have added code in the answers because they code was too large for the comment. And this code will display where you are able to create your character however the URL does not seem to work on my computer. However, I would need the URL to upload the players code to the profile picture.